# How to get Hadoop task tracker info from inside a mapper or reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, task-tracking

Your Mapper and Reducer classes always run on a particular task tracker.  But how do I get info on the task tracker?  The only thing passed into the `setup` method is a TaskInputOutputContext.  You can get the task attempt ID, but how do I map this to a TaskTracker object? (E.g. to get the hostname, the corresponding job tracker, etc.  Yes I know you can get the hostname through `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` but this is outside of Hadoop entirely.)

Comment: Please hint the problem you want to solve

Answer (score 0):

you can anytime got to the MapReduce web-ui and see all these information..just click on a job you want to analyze and then you can see almost everything for individual map and reduce tasks.